# In the Diffie Hellman Key exchange, why is a value of $a=\frac{p-1}{2}$ a bad choice?

Tags: diffie-hellman

In Diffie Hellman key exchange, we have a large prime $p$ and non zero residue class $g \in F_p^x$ with a large order.  An $a$ and $b$ are chosen in secret, and those are used to compute $A \equiv g^a \mod p$ and $B \equiv g^b \mod p$.

Then the two communicating agree on value $g^{ab}$ via $A^b$ and $B^a$.

$a=p-1$ would be a bad choice (by Euler Fermat theorem). My question is why is the value of $a = \frac{p-1}{2}$ a bad choice?

Comment: hint : what is $g^{p-1} \equiv$ ?

Comment: hint 2: $p$ is often chosen such that $p = 2q + 1$ where $q$ is also prime.

Comment: I would strongly encourage studying the two hints of kelalaka and puzzlepalace from a finite field and number theoretic perspective as these properties/relationships are fundamental to understanding the correctness, security, and difficulty of the problem on which the security relies. A couple excellent resources giving this information are Pinter's Book of Abstract Algebra, and Menezes' Handbook of Applied Cryptography.

Answer (score -1):

In Diffie-Hellman besides $p$ being prime, if the factorization of $p-1$ comprises at least one big prime $k$ such that $p=2k+1$ (can be also $jk+1$, this is a safe prime). In the worst case if the factorization is composed of computable factors then we can compute $x$ using the direct product of cyclic groups (Pohlig-Hellman).

Normally, if $p$ is prime and $g$ a generator with order $p-1$ then $g^{\frac{(p-1)}{2}} \equiv p-1 \equiv -1 \pmod p$

If $g$ is a generator of the subgroup of prime order $k$, where $k$ is large enough then $g^{\frac{(p-1)}{2}} \equiv g^k \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Both congruences are deterministic as you can see.

Generally, two congruences are related by symmetry, since both have the same square root mod p:

$$g^a \equiv -(g^b) \pmod p \quad \iff b = x-d, \ d = \frac{p-1}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:** yes bad choice since it is $-1$. Let see; why;

---

**Lemma:** If $p$ is prime and $g$ is a generator $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ then $g^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1$.

*proof:* by Little Fermat Theorem we know that  $g^{(p-1)} \equiv 1$. Take the square root of both sides.

$$g^{(p-1)/2} \equiv 1^{1/2}$$

the square root of $1$ is either $-1$ or $1$. If $g^{(p-1)/2} \equiv  1$ implies that $g$ has a shorter order than $p-1$, this contradicts that $g$ is generator. Then $g^{(p-1)/2} \equiv -1 $

---

Now, in case of $p = 2 q +1$ than $\beta = g^q = q^{(p-1)/2} = -1$. Than an attacker may force the key aggreement as fallows;

replace the messages $g^x$ and $g^y$ by $(g^x)^q$ and $(g^y)^q$ then the key agreement will be as $g^{xyq} = \beta^{xy} \equiv \pm1$

To prevent this attack use digital signatures.